# Error "Unable to find resource id "

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want login Facebook on Android by use FacebookSDK .

Here MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ViewPager myViewPager;
private FragmentAdapter myFragmentAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    myFragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    myViewPager.setAdapter(myFragmentAdapter);
}
}
```

And LoginFragment.class

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginButton loginButton;

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile myProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        if (myProfile != null)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    myProfile.getFirstName() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};

public LoginFragment() {
    Log.d("LOG", "LoginFragment()");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("LOG", "ON CREATE VIEW");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("LOG", "ON CREATE");
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("LOG", "ViewCreated");
    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, mCallback);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

And here is activity_main layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ngoc.sharemyphoto.MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and login layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I set up on Mainifest . 
My app show a button login. but when i click that button , my app is stop working. And here my logcat

```
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487): Process: com.ngoc.sharemyphoto,  PID: 7487
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.ngoc.sharemyphoto/com.facebook.FacebookActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f080012
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f080012
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:3017)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:934)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:571)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1177)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5590)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
08-23 16:49:01.320: E/AndroidRuntime(7487):     ... 11 more
```

How can i fix it? Thanks for reading my question!

[image]

Comment: Have you set your *app Id* in Manifest? From documentation of LoginButton:  "A Log In/Log Out button that maintains login state and logs in/out for the app.

This control requires the app ID to be specified in the AndroidManifest.xml."

Comment: have you properly imported android.support.v4  to your project ?.

Comment: yes. i have. my app ran and show button login. but when i click , it stop

Comment: Try to replace `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);` with `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, true);`

Comment: OMG. I don't know why i change "false" to true, it stop working . But when I change "true" to false I work . I have login to facebook . :) . thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Move the code to :

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("LOG", "ON CREATE VIEW");
    ViewGroup root =  (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
     loginButton = (LoginButton) root.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, mCallback);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Can't indentify ViewGroup root.

Comment: You need to cast it to ViewGroup

Answer (score 1):

Set **inflater return** **`true`** instead **`false`** .

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login,container,true);
```